# Collect funds from bifrost after an ICO

Tags: accounts, bifrost, ico

[Bifrost](https://github.com/stellar/go/tree/master/services/bifrost) creates a lot of wallets after an ICO. I was wondering what is the best method to collect these funds into a single wallet and whether anyone has built an automated system for this?

Answer (score 1):

All accounts are stored in the Postgres db. I think you have to get the private keys of the ETH accounts and then send the funds to the main account.

To generate a private key for an ETH account you have to use BIP39 libraries.

Comment: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/774/bifrost-how-to-access-eth-received-after-ico

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to find keys in your database, they will be sequential.

You can read the document on github or even raise an issue with the owner in case you hae troubles.

---